# Devstack Services

Tags: openstack, devstack, ceilometer

I have installed ceilometer services in a devstack environnement by enabling them in local.conf"

```
enable_service ceilometer-acompute ceilometer-acentral ceilometer-anotification$
enable_service ceilometer-alarm-evaluator,ceilometer-alarm-notifier
enable_service ceilometer-api
enable_service ceilometer-aipmi
```

but I can not list the services when I do a rejoin-stack.sh and type `Ctrl + a + "`.

How I should resolve this problem, because I need to restart the ceilometer services as I am installing kwapi ?

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1):

Ceilometer is middleware that is used by the other services.  To "restart ceilometer" you should restart the entire stack with ./unstack.sh followed by ./stack.sh.  If you want to uninstall and re-install, you could run ./clean.sh followed by ./stack.sh.

Answer (score 0):

When you wanna restart services with devstack, have 2 main ways:

1. Run ./rejoin-stack.sh and press ctrl C + ctrl D to kill all services. Then re-run ./rejoin_stack.sh and press ctrl A + ctrl D for detaching. Then, all services were restarted.
2. Run "ps -ef | grep your_service_name" to find and kill the service that you need to restart. When you run above command, you will find the exact command to start that service. :D

But, I recommend you use the first way when restart any service with devstack. It is the best way to make your system run smoothy.

Answer (score 0):

- First cd to folder devstack

  - You can find the file ./rejoin_stack.sh
  - Execute the same.
  - It will be executed and screen will be opened for access.
  - press ctrl + a + shift + "
  - Then it will be listing the running services
  - can move to service which needs to be stopped by scrolling towards it.
  - on the service which is needs to be stopped press enter
  - then press ctrl + c , it will stop the service
  - then press up arrow key to run the service again
  - service will be restarted successfully.